# Variable in JS File to HTML File

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a JS File with an Array in it and Im trying to pas that array to html file so i can get elements using it. The issue is that im using node to write the page. Anyone have any ideas? Ive check a few pages but cant seem to find a solution.

```
{'image1.jpeg','image2.jpeg','image3.jpeg','image4.jpeg'}
```

to an html file

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into using [templates with express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html):

Ex using pug:

Template:

```
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= message
```

Express app:

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' })
})
```